# Hudson leaving open sessions

Tags: svn, session, hudson, version-control

Does anyone have any experiences with Hudson leaving sessions open to a Subversion server?

We've been increasing our job list and got ~50 which poll the SCM regularly. It's been working fine but recently our SCM has started acting up by refusing handshakes, which we suspect is down to the sessions left open by Hudson.

Last count there were ~400 sessions with nothing building on Hudson. At the moment the only solution we've found is restarting the Subversion service but this is becoming increasingly frequent and not a long term solution.

Any experiences/ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Hudson version are you using?

Comment: Updated to the latest (1.353) last week - still having problems. Also updated the Subversion plug-in to 1.16 then spent all morning patching it with the 1.17 fix...

Answer (score 0):

Do you restart your Hudson server frequently without doing a Prepare for Shutdown on the Manage Hudson page first?  It is possible the server could be in the middle of querying the Subversion server and someone simply stopping and restarting the app could leave sessions open.

Also, which Subversion Authentication method are you using for your jobs?

Comment: Hudson isn't stopped very often and we always do a prepare first before stopping the service in tomcat.
The subversion auth is username/pw over ssl

Comment: @James Carr:  How often do you have your jobs set up to Poll the SCM?

Comment: @James Carr:  Also, if you stop Hudson do the connections go away or do you have to restart the Subversion server to clear the connections?

Comment: It was every minute changed to every 5 minutes now. Stopping Hudson clears the connections.